# SDL 9.5 Experience Space Url to access

Tags: sites-9.5, experience-space

What is the url for accessing the Experience Space CM interface ?
Is it different than the classic interface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is under `/ui` endpoint.

So `your-tridion/ui/`

Comment: Thank you Marko.